# solr commit slow - solrCloud only one collection commit slow

Tags: performance, solr, commit, difference, solrcloud

**Backgroud**
solrCloud only set 1 shard - 6 replicas.
There are 2 solr collections A + B, each replica has 2 cores (A + B).
A and B share the same solrConfig.xml and schema, A has bigger index size (more than 40GB), B only has ~1GB index.

**Problem**
A and B has similar commit frequency, they both don't do autoCommit, every time there is a new document, one hard commit will be made(the frequency is low, often less than 100 commits one day).

However, A always cost less than 100 ms to finish 1 commit, B always cost more than 5000 ms to finish 1 commit, even when they both commit a same one small document which less than 2KB. Since A has much bigger index size, shouldn't B cost less time?

I'm 100% sure that these 2 collections have the same configs, but the performance difference really confuses me a lot. I'm struggling to figure out why B collection has such different performance.

Don't know if this matters, even A and B have the same schema, there is one field that A never used, but B has plenty of documents with this field filled with values (quite long texts).

Here is the solrConfig.xml used for A + B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_41</luceneMatchVersion>
    <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>

    <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"
                      class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/>

    <indexConfig />
    <jmx />

    <!-- The default high-performance update handler -->
    <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">

        <updateLog>
            <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
        </updateLog>

        <autoCommit>
            <maxTime>15000</maxTime>
            <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
        </autoCommit>
    </updateHandler>


    <searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggestComponent">
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">default</str>
            <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
            <!-- Alternatives to lookupImpl:
                 org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.FSTLookup   [finite state automaton]
                 org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.WFSTLookupFactory [weighted finite state automaton]
                 org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.jaspell.JaspellLookup [default, jaspell-based]
                 org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup   [ternary trees]
            -->
            <str name="field">autocomplete</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
            <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
            <!--
                  <str name="sourceLocation">american-english</str>
            -->
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>
    <requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
            <!--str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str-->
            <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
            <!--str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str-->
        </lst>
        <arr name="components">
            <str>suggestComponent</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>


    <!-- Highlighting Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters
    -->
    <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
        <highlighting>
            <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
            <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
            <fragmenter name="gap"
                        default="true"
                        class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
                <lst name="defaults">
                    <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
                </lst>
            </fragmenter>

            <!-- A regular-expression-based fragmenter
               (for sentence extraction)
            -->
            <fragmenter name="regex"
                        class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
                <lst name="defaults">
                    <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
                    <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
                    <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
                    <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
                    <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
                    <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
                </lst>
            </fragmenter>

            <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
            <formatter name="html"
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
                <lst name="defaults">
                    <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
                    <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
                </lst>
            </formatter>

            <!-- Configure the standard encoder -->
            <encoder name="html"
                     class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />

            <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
            <fragListBuilder name="simple"
                             class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>

            <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
            <fragListBuilder name="single"
                             class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>

            <!-- Configure the weighted fragListBuilder -->
            <fragListBuilder name="weighted"
                             default="true"
                             class="solr.highlight.WeightedFragListBuilder"/>

            <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
            <fragmentsBuilder name="default"
                              default="true"
                              class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
                <!--
                <lst name="defaults">
                  <str name="hl.multiValuedSeparatorChar">/</str>
                </lst>
                -->
            </fragmentsBuilder>

            <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
            <fragmentsBuilder name="colored"
                              class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
                <lst name="defaults">
                    <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
               <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
               <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
               <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
               <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
               <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
                    <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
                </lst>
            </fragmentsBuilder>

            <boundaryScanner name="default"
                             default="true"
                             class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
                <lst name="defaults">
                    <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
                    <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
                </lst>
            </boundaryScanner>

            <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator"
                             class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
                <lst name="defaults">
                    <!-- type should be one of CHARACTER, WORD(default), LINE and SENTENCE -->
                    <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
                    <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale object.  -->
                    <!-- And the Locale object will be used when getting instance of BreakIterator -->
                    <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
                    <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
                </lst>
            </boundaryScanner>
        </highlighting>
    </searchComponent>

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         Query section - these settings control query time things like caches
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <query>
        <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>

        <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                     size="512"
                     initialSize="512"
                     autowarmCount="0"/>

        <!-- Query Result Cache

             Caches results of searches - ordered lists of document ids
             (DocList) based on a query, a sort, and the range of documents requested.
          -->
        <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                          size="512"
                          initialSize="512"
                          autowarmCount="0"/>

        <!-- Document Cache

             Caches Lucene Document objects (the stored fields for each
             document).  Since Lucene internal document ids are transient,
             this cache will not be autowarmed.
          -->
        <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                       size="512"
                       initialSize="512"
                       autowarmCount="0"/>

        <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
        <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
        <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
        <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
            <arr name="queries">
                <!--
                   <lst><str name="q">solr</str><str name="sort">price asc</str></lst>
                   <lst><str name="q">rocks</str><str name="sort">weight asc</str></lst>
                  -->
            </arr>
        </listener>
        <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
            <arr name="queries">
                <lst>
                    <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
                </lst>
            </arr>
        </listener>
        <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
        <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>
    </query>


    <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false" >
        <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true"
                        multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                        formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"/>

        <httpCaching never304="true" />
    </requestDispatcher>

    <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
        <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
             will be overridden by parameters in the request
          -->
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
            <int name="rows">10</int>
            <str name="defType">edismax</str>
            <str name="qf">
                entityId^1 entityName^1 text^0.5
            </str>
            <str name="fl">*,score</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>

    <!-- A request handler that returns indented JSON by default -->
    <!--requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
       <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
         <str name="wt">json</str>
         <str name="indent">true</str>
         <str name="df">text</str>
       </lst>
    </requestHandler-->

    <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
        <!-- See below for information on defining
             updateRequestProcessorChains that can be used by name
             on each Update Request
          -->
        <!--
           <lst name="defaults">
             <str name="update.chain">dedupe</str>
           </lst>
           -->
    </requestHandler>

    <!-- for back compat with clients using /update/json and /update/csv -->
    <!--
    <requestHandler name="/update/json" class="solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler">
          <lst name="defaults">
           <str name="stream.contentType">application/json</str>
         </lst>
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/update/csv" class="solr.CSVRequestHandler">
          <lst name="defaults">
           <str name="stream.contentType">application/csv</str>
         </lst>
    </requestHandler>
    -->

    <!-- Solr Cell Update Request Handler

         http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler

      -->
    <requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                    startup="lazy"
                    class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="lowernames">true</str>
            <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>

            <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
            <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
            <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
            <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>

    <!-- Admin Handlers

         Admin Handlers - This will register all the standard admin
         RequestHandlers.
      -->
    <!--
    <requestHandler name="/admin/" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
    -->
    <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
        <lst name="invariants">
            <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">all</str>
        </lst>
        <!-- An optional feature of the PingRequestHandler is to configure the
             handler with a "healthcheckFile" which can be used to enable/disable
             the PingRequestHandler.
             relative paths are resolved against the data dir
          -->
        <!-- <str name="healthcheckFile">server-enabled.txt</str> -->
    </requestHandler>

    <!-- Echo the request contents back to the client -->
    <requestHandler name="/debug/dump" class="solr.DumpRequestHandler" >
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
            <str name="echoHandler">true</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
    </requestHandler>

    <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">
        <!-- For the purposes of the tutorial, JSON responses are written as
         plain text so that they are easy to read in *any* browser.
         If you expect a MIME type of "application/json" just remove this override.
        -->
        <str name="content-type">text/plain; charset=UTF-8</str>
    </queryResponseWriter>



    <!-- Legacy config for the admin interface -->
    <admin>
        <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
    </admin>

</config>
```

Could anyone help me figure out the root cause of the slow commit for B collection? I'll appreciate it a lot if anyone could help!